# using HTTP HttpWebRequest to extract sharepoint data in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I am trying to read a sharepoint site using HttpWebRequest, but the below code throws an exception (403 Forbidden):

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/it/abc/ScriptAttest/docs/");
r.Method = "GET";
WebResponse rs = r.GetResponse();
```

I get the same response if I add

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "secret");
```

(using my domain credentials of course)

or specify default credentials.

However, if I create a browser control (called documentBrowser) and execute the following:

```
documentBrowser.Navigate(@"https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/it/abc/ScriptAttest/docs/");
```

I get the data.  However, it takes a long time, and I don't really need to display the page.  My objective is to parse the html and only pull out certain elements.  Additionally, the data comes in stages and the control triggers the DocumentCompleted event after each segment, so I don't really know when the entire page has loaded.

Comment: If you are trying to get data out of SharePoint, there are better options that loading the website in a HttpWebRequest.  The [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) supports getting and saving data that your user account has access to, or in C# you can get the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/) to use the [Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online does not support `NetworkCredential`. `documentBrowser.Navigate` in fact use the embed IE browser which may has some SPO related cache, thus it could navigate to the site. If you want to fetch data from SPO, you could use Rest API or CSOM. If you just want to access the site page, you may consider using cookie to get it:

```
var login    = "admin@***.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "P@ssw0rd";
var siteUrl  = "https://***.sharepoint.com/";

var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, password);
var auth  = creds.AuthenticateAsync(new Uri(siteUrl), true);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteUrl);
request.CookieContainer = auth.Result.CookieContainer;

var result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

BR